# Are there general guidelines for efficiently using hybrid parallelization with OpenMP and MPI?

Tags: mpi, openmp

I am planning to run a large simulation case on a supercomputer. Each single node offers 48 physical cores with the number of physical cores per processor being 24. I am not sure how to efficiently distribute my case into MPI and OpenMP threads. For example, I could parallelize it such that I get 512 MPI threads. Now, I can stack up to 24 OpenMP threads on top of that, but to my understanding every additional OpenMP thread will increase the total number of nodes required, for example, using a SLURM nomenclature:

```
ntasks=512 - ntasks-per-node=48 - cpus-per-task=1 -> ~10 nodes required
ntasks=512 - ntasks-per-node=24 - cpus-per-task=2 -> ~21 nodes required
...
ntasks=512 - ntasks-per-node=2 - cpus-per-task=24 -> 256 nodes required
```

Using 512 tasks corresponds to a guideline I know for using MPI-only parallelization. However, I could also use way less MPI threads, for example 128:

```
ntasks=128 - ntasks-per-node=48 - cpus-per-task=1 -> ~2.7 nodes required
ntasks=128 - ntasks-per-node=24 - cpus-per-task=2 -> ~5.3 nodes required
...
ntasks=128 - ntasks-per-node=2 - cpus-per-task=24 -> 64 nodes required
```

Obviously, the first block of tasks will run faster, but as I have no endless access to nodes I have to find an efficient solution for the parallelization. For example, let's say I can use only 10 nodes and therefore a total of 480 physical cores.
To my understanding, one possible extreme option would be to do the following:

```
ntasks=20 - ntasks-per-node=2 - cpus-per-task=24 -> 48 nodes required
```

The extreme counterpart would be:

```
ntasks=480 - ntasks-per-node=48 - cpus-per-task=1 -> 48 nodes required
```

I am a bit unsure how to find a good balance between these to run my simulation as efficient / fast as possible. Are there any guidelines for hybrid parallelization?

Comment: this is highly application dependent. My rule of thumb is to never run a MPI tasks on more than one socket in order to avoid NUMA effect that generally has a bad impact on OpenMP performances. Since you have 24 cores per socket, and unless you have exceptional OpenMP parallelization, Amdahl's law suggests you might want to run more than one MPI tasks per socket. 2 or 4 could be the sweet spot, but once again, this is highly application dependent. Last but not least, make sure your app is correctly pinned (this is a two steps tango, MPI on a set of adjacent cores first, and the OpenMP threads)